# Highlight specific words with different color codes on a text file opened on a website

Tags: javascript, html

I am not a programmer (but try to create small programming solutions for my day-to-day work).
This time I am trying to build a log analyzer that will highlight specific keywords on the log file(.txt) when it is opened on a browser.
The log file will be on a log server and will have a specific URL.
I want to use that URL on the log analyzer page and open that text file, once the text file is loaded the javascript will highlight the keywords that I have mentioned(static) on the javascript.

I tried using mark.js solution.

```html
<body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit āmet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, nò sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie çonsequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit prāesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

    <script>
        var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("body"));
        instance.mark(["ipsum", "lorem"], {
               "accuracy": "exactly"
        });
        $('mark').css({'background':'transparent' , 'color':'yellow'});
    
    </script>

</body>
```

But mark.js only gives the option to highlight words with single-color code(in the above code I used yellow) but I want the keywords to be highlighted with different colors like for example the **info keywords highlighted with yellow, error keywords highlighted with red and success keywords highlighted with green**. What solution I can use here to accomplish my goal? any help is appreciated.

Also how I can open a text file using the URL and make the JS work on it. I tried the HTML OBJECT tag but then the javascript was not working on it (not highlighting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will have to rely on css classes for styling**

then pass the class to the `className` attribute in the `options` dictionary in the proper call. We can use one object and chain call the `mark()` method as follows:

```js
// create Mark.js instance
var marker = new Mark('body')
// create lists for easy updating of search terms
info_words = ['lorem', 'ipsum']
err_words = ['sit','et']
success_words = ['dolor','te']
// chain mark method calls together
marker.mark(info_words,{accuracy:'exactly'})
   .mark(err_words, {
   accuracy:'exactly',
   className:'err'
})
   .mark(success_words, {
   accuracy: 'exactly',
   className:'success'
})
```

```css
.err
{
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
.success
{
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit āmet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, nò sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie çonsequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit prāesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried doing this but looks like the last $('mark').css({'background':'transparent' , 'color':'red'}); that i mention in the script overrides all the previous instances.
so all the words are now in red.

Comment: @Sachin i have updated the solution, does it work any better or is it still overriding?

Comment: still the same. https://codepen.io/sachinkr91/pen/LYeJOpm 
still overriding

Comment: @Sachin finally figured it out, updated answer contains snippet that should run fine :)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is without Mark js:

Step 1. get the HTML content of the paragraph.
Step 2. use Regular Expressions to find the value in the original text.
Step 3. replace the original text with a text added `span` dom element.

```js
const text = document.querySelector("p");
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const originalTxt = text.innerHTML;

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  mark();
});

function mark() {
  const inputValue = input.value;
  const regex = new RegExp(inputValue, "gi");
  text.innerHTML = originalTxt.replace(
    regex,
    `<span style="color:red;">${inputValue}</span>`
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>Mark!</button>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit āmet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, nò sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie çonsequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit prāesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
```

Comment: I tried this https://codepen.io/sachinkr91/pen/WNdgvbL but it seems that it doesnt solve the purpose. your solution wants me to input the value dynamically and then it highlights the word. I want to define all the keywords(static) already on the code and the script highlights them on load.

Comment: Sorry, there was the input added the eventListener, not the button! Try now, I corrected it.

Comment: I reworked my solution, It is more clear and understandable.

Comment: it still doesn't solve OP's problem. they require the ability to simultaneously highlight muiltiple words as well as the ability to support multiple colors. you have presented a solution completely outside the scope of this question. OP never asked for the ability to dynamically change the search word.

Answer (score 1):

I did it without mark.js . The code is commented check if is this what you want? Basically i found all occurences of words in the array ["ipsum", "lorem"] and i switch the word for the same word inside a element  with class color.

```js
//function to replace word for element with class
function switchKeyWordsToElement(words, color){  
  var text = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML
  
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    var finalText = text.split(words[i]).join('<span class="' + color + '">' + words[i] + '</span>');
    text = finalText
  }
  //add to <p></p> final text
  document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = text
}

//lists of words to search
const yellowWords = ["ipsum", "Lorem"]
const redWords = ["sit", "elitr"]

//switch yellow words
switchKeyWordsToElement(yellowWords, 'yellow')
//switch red words
switchKeyWordsToElement(redWords, 'red')
```

```css
.red{
  color: red;
}

.yellow{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit āmet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, nò sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie çonsequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit prāesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
  </body>

</html>
```